# Replacement in file with sed with specific condition

Tags: bash, sed, replace

I have a file with many occurences of a string. For instance:

```
Bergson 
BErgson Bergso
\a{Henri Bergson}
Henri BERgson bergson
```

I want to encapsulate the word `Bergson` (with unsensitive case) in `\a{...}` but only if the word is not already inside the command `\a{...}`.

So the result must be

```
\a{Bergson} 
\a{BErgson} Bergso
\a{Henri Bergson}
Henri \a{BERgson} \a{bergson}
```

I am trying using `sed` but it was too complicated for me or maybe it is not the right tool.

Do you have any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With gnu sed:

```
$ sed '/\\a{.*bergson.*}/I! s/bergson/\\a{&}/gI'
\a{Bergson} 
\a{BErgson} Bergso
\a{Henri Bergson}
Henri \a{BERgson} \a{bergson}
```

Alternative:

```
sed '/\\a{.*bergson.*}/In; s/bergson/\\a{&}/gI' file1
```

Comment: George: would be curious how you would tackle the 3rd line of MiniMax's sample data - `\a{...Bergson} bergson \a{Bergson}` ... or any line that has a mix of `\a{...bergson ...}` and `bergson`; it's not in the OP's sample data so don't know if it would be a realistic example

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou Thank you.

Comment: @markp your remark is correct but in fact the solution corresponds better with my global trouble but my question was in fact incomplete.

Comment: Is it possible to avoid to go to a new line using sed? for instance if I have on a same line `\a{Henri Bergson} Henri BERgson \a{Henri Bergson prout}` the result must be `\a{Henri Bergson} Henri \a{BERgson} \a{Henri Bergson prout}`

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -r '
s/(\\a\{[^}]*ber)(gson[^}]*\})/\1#\2/Ig; 
s/bergson/\\a{&}/gI; 
s/(ber)#(gson)/\1\2/gI' input.txt
```

**Explanation:**

1. `s/(\\a\{[^}]*ber)(gson[^}]*\})/\1#\2/Ig;` - replaces strings, which shouldn't be touched to the `\a{Henri Berg#son}` (inserts hash sign into the "Bergson" word).

   - `[^}]*` and `[^}]*` are needed for non-greedy matching.
2. `s/bergson/\\a{&}/gI;` - substitutes all needed "bergsons" by the standard way.
3. `s/(ber)#(gson)/\1\2/gI` - removes `#` from the `Berg#son`, reverting it back to the original form.

**Input** (complicated for testing)

```
Bergson                                  
BErgson Bergso
\a{Henri Bergson} bergson \a{Bergson} another words
Henri BERgson bergson
```

**Output**

```
\a{Bergson}                                  
\a{BErgson} Bergso
\a{Henri Bergson} \a{bergson} \a{Bergson} another words
Henri \a{BERgson} \a{bergson}
```